# How to describe 2d table using json?

Tags: json, schema

I have this table :

what is the best json structure, should be used ?

Comment: It's a nice question, but what did you try by yourself? Please, post your JSON and describe why it does not satisfy your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take 2 rows for example:

```
[{
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Age": "0-10",
    "Value": 0
},
{
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Age": "0-10",
    "Value": 4
},
{
    "Gender": "Not Specified",
    "Age": "0-10",
    "Value": 1
},
{
    "Gender": "",
    "Age": "0-10",
    "Value": 5
},
{
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Age": "10-14",
    "Value": 3
},
{
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Age": "10-14",
    "Value": 11
},
{
    "Gender": "Not Specified",
    "Age": "10-140",
    "Value": 1
},
{
    "Gender": "",
    "Age": "10-14",
    "Value": 15
}]
```